# How to get statuscode using Odata in dynamics crm?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, odata, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

By Using Odata Query I am getting the CRM fields. but `statuscode` is of type `OptionSet` how do you get that `statuscode`. I tried the below code its getting Unable to get 0 or Undefined. Could you have any references appreciated.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        datatype: "json",
        url: odata_point + "(guid'" + x + "')",
        beforeSend: function (XMLHttpRequest) { XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json"); },
        success: function (data, textStatus, XmlHttpRequest) {
            RetrieveEntityData(data.d);
            alert(data.d.Name);
            alert(data.d[0].StatusCode.Value); //here i'm getting Unable to get 0 or undefined.
       }
```

Comment: first of all tell me. what mistake i did for down vote.i want to clarify.i want to improve,learn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var retrievedLeadState = data.d.results[0].StateCode;

// StateCode is an OptionSet so we must use eval-function
var stateCode = eval(retrievedLeadState.Value);

alert(stateCode);
```

Ref: [CRM 2011: Retrieve StateCode (Status) using oData (REST) Service Endpoint](http://snipplr.com/view/65999/)